# Representation theorem on dual of bounded continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm working through the proof of the above representation. Let $C_{b}(X)$ be the space of bounded continuous functions on a normal Hausdorf space. I've proven that for any *positive* linear functional $\phi \in (C_{b}(X))^{*}$, there exists a finitely additive positive measure $\mu$ such that
$$ \forall f \in C_{b}(X), \,\,\, \phi(f)=\int_{X} f d\mu. $$

Now I want to extend this to all linear functions $\phi \in (C_{b}(X))^{*}$, not necessarily just positive ones, and prove that there exists a finitely additive *signed* measure $\mu=\mu^{+}-\mu^{-}$ such that
$$ \forall f \in C_{b}(X), \,\,\, \phi(f)=\int_{X} f d\mu^{+}-\int_{X} f d\mu^{-}. $$
The problem is, simply applying the first result for positive linear functionals still seems to leave some serious work to do: Any linear functional $\phi$ can be written as $\phi=\phi^{+}-\phi^{-}$, and hence applying the top result to the positive functionals $\phi^{+}$ and $\phi^{-}$ guarantees me some measures $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ such that $ \forall f \in C_{b}(X)$,
$$\phi(f)=\int_{X} f d\mu_{1}-\int_{X} f d\mu_{2}. $$
However, this does not tell me that $\mu_{1}=\mu^{+}$ and $\mu_{2}=\mu^{-}$ for some signed measure $\mu$. Jordan's decomposition theorem tells us that it need not be the case that simply defining $\mu=\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}$ does the job.

So, I suppose my question then is, given any two positive measures $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$, does there exist a signed measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_{1}=\mu^{+}$ and $\mu_{2}=\mu^{-}$?

Comment: If $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are nonnegative and finitely additive and at least one of them is finite, then $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ is also finitely additive. In the case that $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are countably additive (i.e. measures), then $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ is countably additive, hence a signed measure.

Comment: Mason, thank you. The problem is, while the difference is certainly a signed measure, the difference of integrals (third integral equation above) is not necessarily the definition of the integral of the signed measure $\mu=\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}$ (given in the second integral equation above), because we do not know that $\mu_{1}=\mu^{+}$ and $\mu_{2}=\mu^{-}$.

Comment: If $f \in L^1(X, \mu_1 + \mu_2)$, then using $\mu_+ + \mu_2 = \mu_1 + \mu_-$ we can integrate and subtract to get $\int f d\mu_+ - \int f d\mu_- = \int f d\mu_1 - \int f \,d\mu_2$. This is enough to deduce what you want.

Comment: That's clever. The theorem does guarantee that these measures are finite, hence any bounded continuous function would be integrable with respect to a finite measure. Thanks a lot!